# If $X$ is beta distributed, what is the distribution of $X^2$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X\sim \text{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$, what is the distribution of $X^2$?

I’ve seen some papers on the product of two independent beta random variables, but things get quite ugly there. I’m hoping the squared case is simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X\ge0$ and $Y=X^2$, for any $y\ge0$ we have$$P(Y\le y)=P(X\le\sqrt{y})\implies f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}f_X(\sqrt{y}).$$In the case at hand, the PDF on $[0,\,1]$ is$$\frac{1}{2\operatorname{B}(\alpha,\,\beta)}y^{\alpha/2-1}(1-\sqrt{y})^{\beta-1}.$$